# Stereo Camera does not generate depth image

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, 3dcamera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My camera is a usb driverless stereo camera that generate both left and right images into one. I'm trying to get the depth image from the camera but after split the images and running the stereo_image_proc there is no topic as "camera/depth/image" but only compressedDepth and which can not be viewed. Is there any package to generate depth image or convert the compresseddepth to viewable depth image? The topic list is shown below

---

```
/sxs_stereo/disparity
/sxs_stereo/left/camera_info
/sxs_stereo/left/image_color
/sxs_stereo/left/image_color/compressed
/sxs_stereo/left/image_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/left/image_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/left/image_color/compressedDepth
/sxs_stereo/left/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/left/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/left/image_color/theora
/sxs_stereo/left/image_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/left/image_color/theora/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/left/image_mono
/sxs_stereo/left/image_mono/compressed
/sxs_stereo/left/image_mono/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/left/image_mono/compressed/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/left/image_mono/compressedDepth
/sxs_stereo/left/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/left/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/left/image_mono/theora
/sxs_stereo/left/image_mono/theora/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/left/image_mono/theora/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/left/image_raw
/sxs_stereo/left/image_raw/compressed
/sxs_stereo/left/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/left/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/left/image_raw/compressedDepth
/sxs_stereo/left/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/left/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/left/image_raw/theora
/sxs_stereo/left/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/left/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect/compressed
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect/compressedDepth
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect/theora
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect_color
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect_color/compressed
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect_color/theora
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/left/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/points2
/sxs_stereo/right/camera_info
/sxs_stereo/right/image_color
/sxs_stereo/right/image_color/compressed
/sxs_stereo/right/image_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/right/image_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/right/image_color/compressedDepth
/sxs_stereo/right/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/right/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/right/image_color/theora
/sxs_stereo/right/image_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/right/image_color/theora/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/right/image_mono
/sxs_stereo/right/image_mono/compressed
/sxs_stereo/right/image_mono/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/right/image_mono/compressed/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/right/image_mono/compressedDepth
/sxs_stereo/right/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/right/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/right/image_mono/theora
/sxs_stereo/right/image_mono/theora/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/right/image_mono/theora/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/right/image_raw
/sxs_stereo/right/image_raw/compressed
/sxs_stereo/right/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/right/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/right/image_raw/compressedDepth
/sxs_stereo/right/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/right/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/right/image_raw/theora
/sxs_stereo/right/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/right/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect/compressed
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect/compressedDepth
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect/theora
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect_color
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect_color/compressed
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect_color/theora
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/right/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/stereo_image_proc/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/stereo_image_proc/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/stereo_image_proc_debayer_left/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/stereo_image_proc_debayer_left/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/stereo_image_proc_debayer_right/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/stereo_image_proc_debayer_right/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/stereo_image_proc_rectify_color_left/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/stereo_image_proc_rectify_color_left/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/stereo_image_proc_rectify_color_right/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/stereo_image_proc_rectify_color_right/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/stereo_image_proc_rectify_mono_left/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/stereo_image_proc_rectify_mono_left/parameter_updates
/sxs_stereo/stereo_image_proc_rectify_mono_right/parameter_descriptions
/sxs_stereo/stereo_image_proc_rectify_mono_right/parameter_updates
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327640/stereo-camera-does-not-generate-depth-image/) by [mibclaric](https://answers.ros.org/users/43880/mibclaric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [wiki page for stereo_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc) says that is publishes `disparity` and `points2` topics. I see both of those in your output:

```
/sxs_stereo/disparity
/sxs_stereo/points2
```

You can usually use those images for 3D processing, depending on your application. If you really need a depth image for some reason, you can probably find a node to convert the disparity image to a depth image.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mibclaric](https://answers.ros.org/users/43880/mibclaric/) on 2019-07-08**:
Thank you! That makes sense! However, when I try to run the point cloud on rviz, there is an error message showed up that the topic "/sxs_stereo/points2" have an empty frame_ID, I know for the image_publisher I can change the frame_ID by changing the parameter, but there is no parameter in stereo_image_proc for frame_ID. How can I add it? Should I create a tf broadcaster?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-07-08**:
From the `stero_iamge_proc` wiki page:

> Point clouds are generated in the optical frame of the left imager (X Right, Y Down, Z out).

You probably just need to set the frame_id on your left stereo image.